# Layout bug: "Interesting Tags", line wrapping

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

A minor bug in the new design: The "Interesting Tags" box on the front page allows line breaks between a tag and the "x" button next to it. Looks confusing.

Comment: I believe it's always been that way. see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-x-icon-inside-the-tag-in-interesting-ignored-tags I think it's because the new design has different font-size and spacing from the Beta theme, so you're just seeing the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, this is the way it has always worked.

Comment: Well, as it is obviously a bug, shouldn't it be fixed?

Comment: We need a feature to mark a question on CS Theory Meta as an exact duplicate of a question on Meta Stack Overflow.